# CakePHP Cookies could not read from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cookies

I am creating a cookie in CakePHP using `setcookie()` from `/cake/contoller_name/method/parameter this page`. But I could not read this cookie from JavaScript. However, when the above cookie sets from `/cake/contoller_name/method this page`, I can read this cookie from JavaScript.

So I realized we cannot set and change the cookie from the page with parameters. In the server side that in Cake we can read get these cookies, but not from JavaScript. Note: the params are passed in "cake style", not on a regular querystring; e.g.: `/cake/controller/param1/param2`. 
Example Code

**Case 1:** 
URL: /cake/payroll/salary Page: payroll_controller.php

```php
function salary(){ 
    setcookie('TEST_COOKIE','TEST_DATA',0); 
}
```

**Case 2:** 
URL: /cake/payroll/salary/14 Page: payroll_controller.php

```php
function salary(){ 
    setcookie('TEST_COOKIE','TEST_DATA',0); 
}
```

Javascript Code:

```js
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

alert(getCookie('TEST_COOKIE'));
```

I can read the cookie from Case 1 with JS, but not the cookie from Case 2. How can I set cookies on any page from CakePHP and read those cookies from JavaScript?

Comment: Why are you using CakePHP if you are using the 'setcookie' function?

Comment: Read this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to set cookie

```
setcookie('TEST_COOKIE','your data',0,"/");
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 steps that you must follow:

1. Use the CakePHP Cookie Component. Let the framework do the hard tasks: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html
2. Read this article regarding JavaScript and cookies. You will also find here 3 functions that you should use for deleting/creating/reading cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
3. If you use Firefox, install Firebug and use the FireCookie extension: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firecookie/

Latest Firebug already has FireCookie installed.

In FireCookie you can check if the cookies really exist and view their name and value.